# Thread-safe get (accessor method)

Tags: c++, c, multithreading

I'm currently using the following code for thread-safe access of a variable.

```
int gnVariable;

void getVariableValue(int *pnValue)
{
    acquireLock(); //Acquires the protection mechanism
    *pnValue = gnVariable;
    releaseLock(); //Releasing the protection mechanism
}
```

I would like to change my API signature to a more user-friendly

```
int getVariableValue(void);
```

How should I rewrite the function - such that the users of the API don't have to bother about the locking/unlocking details?

Comment: I don't get your question. Neither version of your proposed API exposes locking details.

Comment: if changed to the second version - int getVariable(void) -, the user of the API would have to release/unlock the semaphore manually. if you do not do what Samuel and Naveen suggest

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since you gave C++ as an option, you can wrap the mutex lock/unlock.  You can then return the value directly:

```
class lock_wrapper
{
public:
    lock_wrapper()
    {
        acquireLock();
    }
    ~lock_wrapper()
    {
        releaseLock();
    }
};

int getVariableValue()
{
    lock_wrapper lw;
    return gnVariable;
}
```

This will also come in handy if you ever need to do a lock/unlock around code that can throw an exception.

Comment: any ideas for doing the same in C?

Comment: I used to use Counting Semaphores for this. Counting Semaphores in some RTOSs support the getValue() operation, which operates atomically.

Comment: @sonofdelphi - for C, you should use the technique from Naveen's answer.

Answer (score 8):

You return a copy of the local variable. Something like:

```
int getVariableValue(void)
{
  int local= 0;
  acquireLock();
  local = gnVariable;
  releaseLock();
  return local;
}
```

As a side note, it is better to [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) principle for locking instead of `acquireLock` and `releaseLock` methods.

Comment: the local copy seems somewhat inelegant. :) No other go?

Comment: @sonofdelphi: @R Samuel Klatchko is a better solution. I just wanted to demonstrate how to do it using local copy.

Comment: @sonofdelphi: The local variable should be optimised away by a decent compiler - it will copy the `gnVariable` straight into the return value location.