# Why is reading not thread-safe?

Tags: c++, thread-safety

I was wondering why reading from memory is not thread-safe. Among what I've seen so far, inter alia [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846872/thread-safe-get-accessor-method) question, reading from memory does not appear to be thread-safe.

I've been coding in Python for a while and now getting into C++. I've never heard that reading in Python is not thread-safe.

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but if not, please tell me why reading from memory is not thread-safe.

Comment: I would recommend reading http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers-writers_problem

Comment: Please note that the answers to this question are NOT applicable to Java.  Java is a different language, and reading from a variable in Java is **not necessarily thread safe** ... even if nothing else is writing to it.  There are things that will guarantee that it is thread-safe (volatile, synchronize, etcetera) but the default is not thread-safe, according to the JLS.  (Some people are using this Q&A as justifying incorrect statements about Java ...)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Reading is thread safe, no problems..... until something writes to the location you're reading from, and then... well, hopefully you'll read before the data was changed, or read after the data was changed (in these cases, no worries), but sometimes, just when you really don't want it, you'll read half-way through the write and then you'll get compete garbage data.

The way to mitigate this is to ensure that you only read either before or after any writes, which requires you to check that a write is occurring and thus use a synchronisation lock of some sort. This makes things slower though, as you're obviously checking the lock and then reading instead of reading. If you're working with primitive data types (an int for example) then you can use a CPU synchronisation to speed this up dramatically.

As fr Python, chances are python data is always synchronised for you by the language runtime, if it isn't then you will get the same thread read problems sooner or later. (quick google says yes, [Python will suffer the same problems](https://web.archive.org/web/20201101025814/http://effbot.org/zone/thread-synchronization.htm) is you're not careful)

Comment: Hi @bjbaanb, what would happen if 1 variable is updated EXACTLY AT THE SAME TIME by 2 different threads (Considering there is no synchronization)? I know maybe this is not the right question but it has some relation. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Daniel usually nothing, last one wins. However, there's no guarantee you will write all of it after the other thread, you could end up with half and half of each writer's data. ie still corrupted. Depends on the size of the data, a byte may be perfectly isolated, a 2-64bit word guid might not, larger data structures like a string would almost certainly be borked. This is (one reason) why read-write locks always exclusively lock for writes but allow multiple readers.

Comment: thanks, @gbjbaanb, so, it is ALWAYS recommended to use locks when at least ONE thread (out of many possible) updates something that IS ALSO GOING TO BE read, right, mostly SO THAT THERE IS NO INCONSISTENCY?

Comment: @Daniel why not just ask a new question.

Answer (score 9):

It is thread safe if many threads are reading the same location, until no one attempts to write there.

Consider if thread A is reading something at the same time as thread B is writing at the memory being read. It will generate a `race condition`. The reading result can become invalid or different from launch to launch

Comment: Hi @Andrew does this apply to any programming language, e.g. python?

Answer (score 9):

Reading from memory is thread-safe, reading from memory that can be written to at the same time isn't safe though.

In Python this is less of a problem as a lot of objects are immutable, hence only references are modified in those cases, not the memory itself.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the same thing simultaneously - is safe.
The problem is when something writes to it at the same time.

Consider the following code:

```
int arr_len = 3;
int* arr = new int[arr_len];

void thread_1()
{
    std::cout << arr[arr_len-1];
}

void thread_2(int new_len)
{
    int* temp = new int[new_len];
    for(int i = 0; i < arr_len && i < new_len; ++i)
        temp[i] = arr[i];
    arr_len = new_len;
    delete arr;
    arr = temp;
}
```

Let's suppose that `arr[arr_len]` is done sequentially (first `arr_len` is read, and then `arr`).

What happens when the 2 threads run interleaved?
One of three things can happen:

- No problem - You're lucky!
- `arr_len` is larger than `arr` - UB :(
- `arr` is invalidated (was deleted) - UB :(