# Would a single integer be safe to read while another thread might be writing in it?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a situation with lots of different threads writing and reading some data and mutex overheads are really killing the performance so I'm trying to minimize their usage and duration as much as possible.

Referring to this: [Why is reading not thread-safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11647803/why-is-reading-not-thread-safe)

The accepted answer says that reading data while its potentially being overwritten might produce a corrupted result. It doesn't specify how much data though. I imagine a large array read would be different from a single integer read though since the cpu doesn't write an integer bit by bit, right?

So would an integer (64 bit one when compiled for x64) read be safe from this?

Comment: As far as I know 64-bit values are not safe on x86-64. I would use `std::atomic` if all you need is safe reading.

Comment: "mutex overheads are really killing the performance" - even if this is true (how have you proven it?) is there a way you can redesign the cross-thread communications to minimise contention? Perhaps copying datasets and working on the copies will be faster (hint: almost always).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short: no, this is UB by C++ standard and you should abide by this rule.

Longer explanation: in x86, read and writes to properly aligned memory locations no larger than word size are atomic. However, without synchronisation, compiler can optimise code in non-obvious way: caching values, reordering reads, etc. In these case you might find that changes from one thread are not visible in another at all. Other funny things might happen if you expect some thing to happen in particular order.

Use `atomic<T>` type. It is geared towards perfomance, and might be even lock-free on platform which supports it.

Answer (score 3):

It's not just about reading "corrupt" updates, it's about ordering and visibility of them. You might set a value in one thread and never see it in another. You might set two variables in order and have them change in the reverse order in another thread. You might set a variable to 1 in one thread and then 2 in another thread and have a third thread read 1 and and fourth see 2 at the same time.

On an x86_64 you are probably safe from most of these, but nothing the C++ standards guarantees that unless you use the facilities meant to handle this.

It's worse than that though.

If you write:

```
while(flag == 0) do_thing();
```

In one thread, thinking you can write 1 in another thread to exit the loop, it might not work. The compiler is allowed to assume that the value of data won't change under it and not actually test it every loop.
Again, use the facilities provided to guarantee it works.

You should use `std::atomic<int>`, and it will be safe and as efficient as you can safely do on the platform. If you really know what you are doing, you can use atomics with release and acquire semantics to be more efficient - but, based on the fact that you asked this question, you probably shouldn't without doing a lot more research, and just use the default mode for atomic.

Answer (score 1):

From a formal and language perspective, the behaviour is undefined, so no, it is not safe.

From a practical point of view, it probably will, because an `int` should be a CPU atomic type (i.e. a read or write is a single instruction and memory cannot be accessed in parallel).

Just use `std::atomic<int>` and be (safely) done with it.

Answer (score 1):

Formally it's undefined behaviour, so the compiler can decide not to do what's "reasonable".  Even with a "friendly" compiler, it also depends what you call "safe", and on the architecture.  Let's also assume you're writing on a 64-bit aligned address, which is necessarily aligned with some single page of cache.

Without proper synchronisation, one thread's update may not become visible to other threads that read from the value afterwards, at all or for some period of time, or they might even see some intermediate value (e.g. if the compiler decided that multiplying by 3 was going to be done by reading the value into a CPU register, and adding that back to the memory location twice).  A thread reading a stale value may update therefrom (e.g. adding a number), clobbering some other thread's update.

Still, in practice it *may* be ok if you've only one updating thread and you don't care if the updates are visible to other threads in any particular timeframe (e.g. you're updating thread's setting a flag to say Control-C has been pressed, and the application can shutdown at the next convenient moment, but it doesn't matter if it's after 1ms or 2 seconds), you're likely ok.

Otherwise, use atomics or some locking, thread-local storage or whatever other safe optimisations you can think of.

Comment: "you're likely ok", as in, your code will work fine in testing and fail when you show it to your most important customer. <g>

Comment: @PeteBecker: practically there are reasons the compiler/implementation must arrange a write back of updates towards main memory in certain circumstances, as e.g. it's calling code whose implementation wasn't known when the updating code was compiled, because it can't know whether that will access the same memory.  Butenhoff's classic comp.programming.threads FAQ Q56 explanation of why `volatile`'s not necessary in multi-threaded code ties in, no?