# c++ thread local counter implement

Tags: c++, thread-local

I wanna implement a high performance counter in multi-thread process, like this, each thread has a thread local counter named "t_counter" to count query(incr 1/query) and in "timer thread" there is a counter named "global_counter", what I want is each second, global_counter will get each t_counter(s) and add them to global_counter, but I dont know how to get each t_counter value in "timer thread". additional, which section will thread local value lay in main memory ? .data or heap or other? how to dynamic allocate memory size(there maybe 10 thread or 100 thread) ? and does x86-64 use segment register store such value?

Comment: "but I dont know how to get each t_counter value in 'timer thread'", I store t_counter pointer to solve the problem

Comment: I would NOT design it this way. Better to have all threads send their `counter` value as a message to a management class every so much time (message passing). Prefer not to use shared memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with your second question, you can find all the specifications [here](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/tls.pdf).

Summarizing, thread local variables are defined in .tdata / .tbss. Those are somewhat similar to .data, however accessing those is different. These sections are replicated per thread. The actual variable offset is computed at the runtime.

A variable is identified by an offset in .tdata. Speaking of x86_64 it will use the FS segment register to find the TCB (Thread control block), using the data structures stored there it will locate the thread local storage where the variable is located. Note that all allocations are done lazily if possible.

Now, regarding your first question - I am not aware of a way to just list all the thread local variables from another thread, and I doubt it is available.

However, a thread can take a pointer to thread variable, and pass it to another thread. So what you probably need is some registration mechanism.

Each new thread will register itself to some main store, then unregister on termination. Registration and deregistration are on your responsibility.

Schematically, it would look like this:

```
thread_local int counter = 0;
std::map<std::thread::id, int *> regs;

void register() {
    // Take some lock here or other synchronization, maybe RW lock
    regs[std::this_thread::get_id()] = &counter;
}
void unregister() {
    // Again, some lock or other synchronization
    regs.erase(std::this_thread::get_id());
}

void thread_main() {
    register();
    counter++;
    unregister();
}

void get_sum() {
    // Again, some lock, maybe only read lock
    return std::accumulate(regs.begin(), regs.end(), 0,
        [](int previous, const auto& element)
        { return previous + *element.second; });
}
```

Comment: But how is this safe? You only lock on registering a pointer to the counter. But increasing the counter is not locked. This is apparently done regularly in the OPs code. This way calling `get_sum` could lead to some read-while-write data race condition.. And locking the `counter`s would also not be great, since that would halt all threads while accumulating.

Comment: @JHBonarius correct, per thread / per cpu counter pattern is good at giving an **approximate** sum while the system is active, or an **accurate** sum if you ensure the system is inactive at that moment. Pay attention though: the sum measured is always <= real sum. Example: if you know you launched 10 threads, each increases sum by 1 - you know that if get_sum() == 10 all threads are terminated, and if not - one thread **may** still be alive. This pattern has its applications, specifically useful in Kernel mode, but it is definitely not fit for all. It is a tool available though.

Comment: Yes, but I'm trying to say: reading and writing `count` is not atomic. Thus ,as it's not guarded a read-while-write could occur. That's UB in C++, thus you should not do that!! edit: e.g. [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37963844)

Comment: @JHBonarius in theory you right, speaking of C++ in general, CPU architecture. In practice, speaking of x86 or arm, this could only be a problem if the counter is exactly on a boundary of two cache lines. Which is not true for a simple global variable. On some micro controller with some weird architecture, or on some custom compiler, it may be a problem, you are right. This all shall be kept in mind when using it. Thats it.

Comment: UB is UB, which you should avoid. Many big issues in production over the years have been caused by people making assumptions while inferring UB. Like the answer I linked before says: _"Use `atomic<T>` type. It is geared towards performance, and might be even lock-free on platform which supports it."_. Or use a different mechanism altogether, like message-passing.

Comment: @JHBonarius Using atomic eliminates all the benefits of using per thread variables. The problem with atomics is not the lock - they are lock free, it is the memory barrier they imply. Just run a simple benchmark. Increase atomic and a regular int by 1 1000 times, you will see the difference in order of magnitude. Often this is not important, but in some critical paths it is, I personally encountered code where you have to count CPU cycles.  So no, I cannot agree with that. This code is not wrong. It is **platform dependent**. Which is valid, just know what you are doing.

Comment: You have no guarantees. It could as well be that if the OP doesn't use `counter` locally to the thread, the compiler will optimize it away. The compiler is allowed to do that, because you indicated that it's thread local. Anyhow, MHO is just that you should not advert UB. "If you know what you are doing" is a very big disclaimer. It's even incomplete as behavior could change between compilers and compiler versions. So it's more "If you know what everybody that's involved in the chain is doing".